# Avoid multiple if/else conditions

Tags: java

using java 6

Have 70+ attributes to check as below. What is the best way to refactor the code as below?

```
    if(0 == compareField1) {            
        if(0 == compareField2) {
            if(0 == compareField3) {
                if(0 == compareField4) {
                    if(0 == compareField5) {
                        ......
                    } else {
                        return compareField5;
                    }
                } else {
                    return compareField4;
                }
            } else {
                return compareField3;
            }               
        } else {
            result = compareField2;
        }           
    } else {
        result = compareField1;
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to switch from `return` to `result = ` in your `else` statements?

Comment: Also are these `compareFields` in an `array/ArrayList`?

Comment: Are you just looking for the first field that's *not* 0?

Comment: please provide more information over your compareFields. Are these instance fields? are they elements of an array or list?

Comment: Have 2 lists. looping thru those lists and comparing objects using comparator for all attributes to check if they are equal. Need to get only objects that are not in the list1.

Answer (score 7):

You can use an integer array where cell with index X will keep value for field numer X

```
final int fieldsCount = 60;
int[] fields = new int[fieldsCount ];
fields = loadFields(); // here you are populating fields

for(int i = 0; i < fieldsCount ; i++) if(fields[i] != 0) return fields[i];

// further logic (else)
```

Comment: I guess he meant the zero checks just as an example. Though I can't be the judge of that, and based on the question this is the most apt answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... something like this?

```
for (int result : Arrays.asList(compareField1, compareField2, ..., compareField5)) {
    if (result != 0) return result;
}
```

Also, have a look at [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#find-java.lang.Iterable-org.apache.commons.collections4.Predicate-)

Answer (score 0):

Without giving an actual code sample.

You have said that:

> Have 2 lists. looping thru those lists and comparing objects using comparator for all attributes to check if they are equal. Need to get only objects that are not in the list1.

I would convert both lists to a set (list1 > set1 and list2 > set2), [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) if the order is irrelevant or [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) if you need the objects in order. Eg.

```
Set<whatevertype> set1 = new HashSet<whatevertype>(list1);
```

Then you can simply use [removeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) items of set1 from set2, like:

```
set2.removeAll(set1);
```

What left is set2', a truncated set of objects those aren't in set1.